# Where do I get SQL Server Compact Edition 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

Last week Guthie announced that SQL Server Compact Edition 4 was released.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx

But in the post he doesn't mention where to get it.  His older post indicated it was to be packaged in VS2010 SP1

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

VS 2010 SP1 is still in beta, so I am a little bit confused.  If I want to start using it now, where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it here

- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2)

The VS2010 change is just to add integrated SQL Server CE management tools to the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Microsoft SQL Server Compact Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx), you can download [Microsoft's Web Platform Installer (or WebMatrix)](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) first or download straight from [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2).

Answer (score 2):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206994 is the download link for SQL Server ce tooling but you need Visual Studio sp1 even in beta mode to be able to design and administer the database

Answer (score 0):

It is available at the Microsoft Download site:

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2)

Version:4.0.8482.1

Date Published:1/12/2011

Answer (score 0):

You're right -- the Visual Studio tooling is a beta product at the moment.

To get started using SQL Server Compact 4, you could:

- use WebMatrix to create your SQL CE databases
- use the VS 2010 SP1 beta