# Connection String in C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am developing C# windows application first time.

Que 1 - ) I have developed my windows application which uses SQL server 2008 using below connection string..

```
Data Source=myMachineName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

But When I created setup of my application and installed it to another computer then it is throwing error of could not establish connection with SQL server..

I guess this error is because of my connection string as it is specific to my computer and installing it to another computer will not work..

Hence How can I make my connection string which will work with any computer..

Que 2 - Do I need to attach schema file with my setup as How my database will be created into   the other computers??

This might be silly qustion but as I am doing this first time , i dont know about this all.

[image]

Regards,
Mahesh

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote database server or local one? If the latter, did you also install the database onto the other computer.

Comment: it is connecting to local server.. Yeah my setup application did install the sql-server to client machine. But i could't connect to database into that

Comment: what's the exact error message, It could be that the sql services haven't started as part of you install.

Comment: @saj check the image i have attached for error message "could not establish the connection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've used SQL Server on your development machine, it has to be installed on every computer that will be using your app. There are several options to resolve this issue:

If your app doesn't need access to a central sql server (for example your app just keeps track of users DVDs), use SQL Server Compact Edition instead and embed it to your app

If your app needs some kind of a centralized data, get a dedicated SQL server first, install there everything you need and in your app change your current myServerAddress to the address of the server. Note that the server needs to be accessible from remote locations (some restrict access to localhost!).

> Que 2 - Do I need to attach schema file with my setup as How my
>   database will be created into the other computers??

Again, multiple options. For instance, you can export your database to a .sql file (Right click on the db in your DB explorer and select option `Publish to provider`) and then import it using a sql manager on other computers. Or maybe you can create a .cs installation script, that will do the same job using C# code.

**Edit based on OP's comments:**

Example links for solutions:

question1: [Embedding SQLServer CE in an installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331295/embedding-sqlserver-ce-in-an-installer)
question2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283

> Okay that's fine but will my current Connection string work in that case as the DataSource 
>   is my specific machine name

Of course not, you'd have to change it to point to the SQL Server CE database file. Probably the best way is to not hardcode it, but use a relative path to the database. It looks like this for instance:

`Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf`, where `|DataDirectory|` points to the `App_Data` folder of your application.

> Also plese see the error screen map i have attach with the question..

Your error is quite clear - there was a problem establishing a connection to your database. It either doesn't exist or isn't accessible from your current machine.

Comment: No my app doesn't need cetralized data. It is just standalone app. But  in connection string myServerAddress is name of my machine..

Comment: @mahesh, yes, I understand. So go with the CE solution then. I don't see a reason why you should force users of your app to install a SQL Server if there's really no need for that. You won't need to solve your second question, because you'll be shipping everything necessary with your app.

Comment: First, how can I go for CE then I have my database in sql server.. Do I need to specify in prerequisites while creating setup as there i have selected for SQL server 2008. Also just chekc my connection string again as in data source I am using name of my machine

Comment: @mahesh, que1: for instance this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331295/embedding-sqlserver-ce-in-an-installer If you use CE, you don't need SQL Server installed.

Comment: So you mean then I do not include SQL SERVER in installer.. Okay that's fine but will my current Connection string work in that case as the DataSource is my specific machine name..I want to make it genarlize..Also plese see the error screen map i have attach with the question.. Thanks for helping

Comment: So for my que2 I need to create database schema and the link you gave me is perfect for it.. For que1- What is sdf file do i need any tool to create that.. I quikly google for it and got many links for it..

Comment: Sdf is an extension of a CE database file. You need to create a CE database to use it, obviously. You can do it easily, `right click on your App_Data folder -> Add new item -> Data -> SQL Server CE` If you can't see anything like it, you might need to install it on your development machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797343/where-do-i-get-sql-server-compact-edition-4

Answer (score 2):

You should place your web config in app.config file which is in xml format.
And read it from your code.You can easily change app.config file through notepad according to machine.

Yes must have your schema script in setup if you want to create it from setup.Otherwise you create database manual on client machine.

Comment: My current connection string is machine specific and I want to make it generalize such that after installing to any machine.. it should work fine.. Do I need to attach scheme script and if yes then how can I run it while installing such that schema on client machine will be created

Comment: Question is your database is centralized or different database for different machines?

Comment: My database is standalone local database means different on different machine

Comment: It means sql server installation is must on each machine.
For your connection string,Use "." or "localhost" in data source attribute.

Comment: SQL Server is their.. buti think placing localhost in place of myMachineName will work